# How to write a TypeScript type that strips a prefix from the keys of another type

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I'm trying to write a type that can strip a given prefix from the keys of another type.

I've tried the following code:

```
type StripPrefix<
  TPrefix extends string,
  T extends `${TPrefix}.${string}`,
> = T extends `${TPrefix}.${infer R}` ? R : never;

type MapKeysStripPrefix<T, TPrefix extends string> = {
  [K in StripPrefix<TPrefix, keyof T & `${TPrefix}.${string}`>]: Pick<
    T,
    keyof T & `${TPrefix}.${string}`
  >[`${TPrefix}.${K}`];
};

type test = {
  'test.blah': 1;
  'test.foo': 2;
  'bar.baz': 3;
};

type result = MapKeysStripPrefix<test, 'test'>;
```

But I get an error:

```
Type '`${TPrefix}.${K}`' cannot be used to index type 'Pick<T, keyof T & `${TPrefix}.${string}`>'
```

I realize it might not be possible to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take advantage of [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) then this is a lot easier:

```
type StripPrefix<
  TPrefix extends string,
  T extends string, // changed this constraint to string
> = T extends `${TPrefix}.${infer R}` ? R : never;

type MapKeysStripPrefix<T, TPrefix extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as StripPrefix<TPrefix, K>]: T[K];
};
```

Here we map over the keys of `T` intersected with `string` to make sure we only have string keys. Then rename those with `as` to `StripPrefix<TPrefix, K>` which will return either the unprefixed string, or removes it form the resul by returning `never`.

And the value type is simply `T[K]` which is the value type of the original prefixed property.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLMAFeEBmiAeAeAsAFBRQAqamOUE2wEAdgCYDOUzCi9A5gDREmlqtBizYdufQgD4oAXjJC6TVgAMAJAG9y6LNgC+AOk2cMEeFABKelVAD8lqAC4o9CADczAbiJFQkKACyAIZgANIQIMxwSKg6OLikPGQUuooirOxI3DLyGvxQANqhUJxQANYRAPYYCgBkYllcUEGs0cgp8dqU2EmhUgC6zqRF-d6EemO+4NCkEOxyUHnEUADkdOwGAEYANkEAFivOAIxjJGtzwAYYlZWHUABMp6ubQfBbQQBedwDMYxM+hD80AscwArttgAtgmEIlEOLFugkLklzuwVlJPEA)

Comment: First time I hear about key renaming, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key is to retain intermediate type argument `K` so that you can use it to index the record for value.

```
type StripPrefix<
  TPrefix extends string,
  T extends `${TPrefix}.${string}`,
> = T extends `${TPrefix}.${infer R}` ? R : never;

type MapKeysStripPrefix<T, P extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T & `${P}.${string}`]: { [N in StripPrefix<P, K>]: T[K] }
}[keyof T & `${P}.${string}`]

type test = {
  'test.blah': 1;
  'test.foo': 2;
  'bar.baz': 3;
  'kk': 5
};

type R = MapKeysStripPrefix<test, 'test'>;

let rec: R = {blah: 1, foo: 2}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLMAFeEBmiAeAeAsAFBRQAqamOUE2wEAdgCYDOUzCi9A5gDREmlqtBiygADACQBvcuizYAvgDpp7JNwVi+hAHxQAvGSF0mrSTIrzl0zhgjwoAJU1QA-E6gAuKPQgA3ewBuIiJQSCgAWQBDMABpCBBmOCRUORxcUh4oFGMRVjVOLj1DKX4oAG1YqE4oAGsEgHsMIwAycWkUaykCjTEAXW8pCoA5avpYDlTKPBQs2J0Bskq+qAUiBXL6kCbW9qlOlW6OXr6QwjDoOnYDKFLiKAByK+AlACMAGyiACwfvAEZgvcnhB2EoMA0Gr8oAAmQEkB6vKLwN5RABeUIAzHDHrValCAKzrQGhcDQRw3aJxBJJSaWdLPLLA9gPHTEwjvCDAKDoADG3nJJQ+33+WXBDW80IUQA)